# Iterating Using Python

Tags: python

I've tried this in Python 2 and 3. All I want to do is return the elements in SERVERS:

```
SERVERS = ['APP 1','APP 2', 'APP3']
n = -1
def get_server():
    n= -1
    n += 1
    return  SERVERS[n % len(SERVERS)]

 if __name__=="__main__":
     get_server()
```

My output is :

```
APP1
```

I'm expecting:

```
APP1
APP2
APP3
APP1
APP2
APP3
APP1
APP2
APP3
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried it this way, expecting the same result but getting the same unexpected result:

```
cycle= itertools.cycle(SERVERS)
def get_server():
    global cycle
    return next(itertools.cycle(cycle))

x= get_server()
print (x)
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Your function is called once, and returns immediately with a single value. If you want to iterate, then you should iterate.

Comment: Every time you call your function, you reset `n` to `-1` before adding one (the first line of the function is `n= -1`). So `n` is always zero (which is the first array index)..

Comment: Thank you Daniel. What I would like to do is loop through and print the items in SERVERS. So that instead of just APP1; I get APP1, APP2, APP3, etc

Comment: Thanks Elliot, that does make sense except it also does the same thing when I use itertools.

Comment: Yes because again you only call it *once*. So you only get one value. Where are you hoping to do the looping?

Comment: Your variable `n` always will have value `0` because `n = -1;n = n + 1` is nothing but `0` and you are calling function only once. Since `n % len(SERVERS)` returns always `0` because `0 % n` always `0`. It always returns 'APP1'

Answer (score 0):

This works in Python 3:

```
SERVERS = ['APP 1', 'APP 2', 'APP3']
n = -1

def get_server():
    global n
    n += 1
    return SERVERS[n % len(SERVERS)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # the number (10) is how many output lines you want to print
    for _ in range(10):
        print(get_server())
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's dry run the code provided by you.
The program starts at the statement

```
 if __name__=="__main__":
```

The next statement it sees is a function call

```
get_server()
```

which it executes just once since it's not iterated over in a loop or by other methods.

Inside the get_server() function, the value of global variable n is set to 0 by the first two lines of the function, which are

```
n = -1
n += 1
```

The function then returns SERVERS[n % len(SERVERS)]. Here,

len(SERVERS) = 3

n = 0

Thus, n % len(SERVERS) = 0 % 3 = 0

This return call asks the function to return SERVERS[0], which, in your case, is APP1, hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SERVERS = ['APP 1','APP 2', 'APP 3']

def get_server():
    for i in SERVERS:
        for i in SERVERS:
            print(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_server()
```